# How to find a partial derivative with theses informations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition, jacobian

Good evening,
I'm struggling on a problem about jacobian and composed functions :
They give a function
$ g(r,\phi) = (rcos(\phi),rsin(\phi)) $

And a the jacobian of a function $f_2$ that is defined as :

$f_2 = f \circ g $    (They give $J_{f_2}$)

Then the sample problem ask to find $\partial f /\partial x$ (not $f_2$)

I thought of calculating the jacobian of Jg and try to get $J_f = J_{f_2}*J_g^{⁻1}$
Then saying $x=rcos(\phi)$ and $y = rsin(\phi) $ But it doesn't work. I already know the answer but It's very hard to find a way to get to it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are $g$ and $G$ the same thing here?

Comment: yeah sorry i'm going to edit this